# .htaccess : Pretty URL with whatever number+names of parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url, rewriting

Hello !
I know there already are a lot of topics about URL rewritting and I honestly swear I've spent a lot of time trying to apply them to my problem but I can't see any of them perfectly applying to my situation (if you find otherwise, please give the link).
-----

Here's the problem :

I'm learning MVC model and URL rewriting and I have my URL like this :

```
http://localhost/blahblahblah/mywebsite/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 ... etc ...
```

What I want (for some MVC template goals) is to have this kind of URL :

```
http://localhost/blahblahblah/mywebsite/value1/value2/value3 ... etc ...
```

-----

**Whatever** are the names of the parameters and **whatever** are the values.
This is the most essential thing I can't find a solution for.

(Also don't mind the localhost blahblahblah, this has to work even on distant websites but I trust it will work fine on online website has this part of URL may have no importance in what I want to do)


***Thanks a lot for your time if you can help me seeing clearer in what I need to do.***

Comment: Where are you wanting to have the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Well, my .htaccess it at the root of the website folder I'm working on how is that related ?

Also, I've found a temporary solution that allows me to do half what I want. Whatever the names of parameters are but not howmuchever there are.

**What I did :**

`# RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4`

and so and so on...

Comment: sorry for the horrible formatting, stackoverflow doesnt let me edit after 5 minutes and there is no beautiful editor when answering comment

/////

anyway what i did is that i do as much line as i need to have number of parameters

Comment: The location of the `.htaccess` determines the URL that needs to be matched by the `RewriteRule` directives. I've just seen your comment after writing my answer below, but yes, that is exactly what you need to do. Why is that a "temporary solution"?

Comment: If you need to provide additional code samples then you should edit your question to include this information (and to retain formatting).

Comment: Thanks for the Stackoverflow tips, I'll write it as I'm sure it will be useful for later topics ! :) Also thanks again for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root (ie. effectively at `http://localhost/.htaccess`) then you would need to do something like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blahblahblah/mywebsite)/(\w+)$ $1/index.php?param1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(blahblahblah/mywebsite)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/index.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(blahblahblah/mywebsite)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/index.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [L]
# etc.
```

Where `$n` is a backreference to the corresponding captured group in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument).

**UDPATE:** `\w` is a shorthand character class that matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore).

A new directive is required for every number of parameters. You could combine them into a single (complex) directive but you would have lots of *empty* parameters when only a few parameters were passed (rather than not passing those parameters at all).

I'm assuming your URLs do not end in a trailing slash.

If, however, the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/blahblahblah/mywebsite` directory then then directives could be simplified a bit:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?param1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
# etc.
```

---

### Don't use URL parameters (alternative method)

An alternative approach is to not convert the path segments into URL parameters in `.htaccess` and instead just pass everything to `index.php` and let your PHP script split the URL into parameters. This allows for any number of parameters.

For example, your `.htaccess` file then becomes rather more simple:

```
RewriteRule ^\w+(/\w+)*$ index.php [L]
```

(This assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in `/blahblahblah/mywebsite` directory, otherwise you need to add the necessary directory prefix as above.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply validates the request URL is of the form `/value1` or `/value1/value2` or `/value1/value2/value3` etc. And the request is rewritten to `index.php` (the front-controller) to handle everything.

In `index.php` you then examine `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse the requested URL.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I did as a temporary solution, the thing is I would like to say, in some way, to the .htaccess file "Detect automatically how much there are parameters and rewrite them". But let's say that for now, for my website project, it will be enough. I just wanted to do some kind of configuration for the "best template possible". Anyway, thanks a lot for interesting to my problems :)

Comment: @BriceJoosten I've added an alternative solution that does not parse the URL into URL parameters in `.htaccess` - this may be more of what you are after. This is certainly more scalable/flexible. You then must parse the URL in your PHP script instead - but this can be more easily adapted to any number of "parameters".

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand this alternative process...

If I'm right... You mean...This rewrite rule make sure the url is in form of something/somethingelse until the end, then I should do a whole script a bit like  `$numberParamGet= count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));` and put each element of the explode (already done it, it results in a php object) in a variable and then I have to pass these variable containing get params as params of functions inside my controllers ? That seems to be doable, I'll try it on a blank test project.

Comment: @BriceJoosten Yes, well kind of, except you are not exploding the query string, but the URL-path (based on `/`). As stated in my answer, using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which contains a string of the form `/value1/value2/value3` etc. based on the requested URL in your example. You then have an array of parameter values.

Comment: What do you mean by " not exploding the query string, but the URL-path " ?
What's the difference ?

Comment: I'm assuming you know the different parts of the URL. eg. in the URL `/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` then `/index.php` is the _URL-path_ (as matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_) and `param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` is the _query string_. Whereas with the URL `/value1/value2/value3` then `/value1/value2/value3` is the URL-path and there is no query string. In the _alternative_ example above that simply rewrites the request to `index.php` (internally) - no query string - then `/value1/value2/value3` is the URL-path and there is no query string.

Comment: ... so in your PHP script you must now parse the URL-path, not the query string. There is no query string, unless you supplied this on the initial request. Note, a slight complication here is that the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the entire URL, not just the URL-path, it also contains the query string (if any).